# Formal Systems Specification in AtelierB - Lhs of binary operator should be a sequence (given type is POW(POW(INTEGERS * ORDERs)))

Tags: logic, computer-science, formal-verification, formal-methods, b-method

I am trying to develop a B specification for a small stock management system and I am battling with the error:

Lhs of binary operator should be a sequence (given type is POW(POW(INTEGERS * ORDERs)))

This is my Abstract Machine:

```
MACHINE
    stock(ORDER, order_limit)
CONSTRAINTS
    order_limit: NAT1
SETS
    PART_COSTS;
    PARTS;
    ORDERS
    
CONSTANTS
    backlog_limit
PROPERTIES 
    backlog_limit: NAT1 & backlog_limit <= 20
VARIABLES
    limit,
    backlog,
    part_quantity
INVARIANT 
    backlog = iseq(ORDERS) & limit : NAT1 & card(backlog) <= limit & limit <= 20 &
    part_quantity : NAT1 & part_quantity >= 200
INITIALISATION
    limit := order_limit || backlog := iseq(ORDERS) || part_quantity := 0
OPERATIONS

     receiveorder(order) =
        PRE 
            order : ORDER & limit > card(backlog)
        THEN
            backlog := backlog <- order
        END
END
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error since backlog is literally a sequence ( I initialised it as a sequence of the set (ORDERS)?

Answer (score 1):

The first occurrence (after its declaration) of the symbol `backlog` is in the following typing predicate: `backlog = iseq(ORDERS)`. So `backlog` is the set of all injective sequences of `ORDERS` values. You probably wanted to have `backlog: iseq(ORDERS)`, i.e., `backlog` is some injective sequence of `ORDERS`.

Of course, you need to change the initialization for `backlog`. You may initialize it with:

- an empty sequence: `backlog := []`
- or any sequence `backlog :: iseq(ORDERS)`
- or any expression of type `iseq(ORDERS)`

Finally, in operation `receiveorder`, the type for the input parameter `order` should be the type of the elements of the `backlog` sequence, that is `ORDERS`, and not `ORDER` (and you do not need machine parameters).